# input.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate myself a field; legit are only number.

This is the simple HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="superficie">Superficie</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control required-field" data-type="number" name="superficie" />
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery:

```
$('.current .required-field').each(function(index) {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        var input_type = $(this).data('type');
        validate($(this), input_type);
    });
});

function validate(input, input_type) {
    switch(input_type) {
        case 'number':
            if (input.value != input.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')) {
                input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Console returns me the error:

> input.value is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `input` variable contains a jQuery object which has no `value` property. To access the value you need to use the `val()` method, or you could provide the native HTMLElement to your function:

```
validate(this, input_type);
```

Finally, it's worth noting is that you can simplify your code as it all hangs off the reference to the element via `this`:

```
$('.current .required-field').keyup(validate);

function validate() {
    var $el = $(this);
    switch ($el.data('type')) {
        case 'number':
            $el.val(function(i, v) {
               return v.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, advise OP on optimizing the event binding. It is right now done inside `.each`

Comment: Also to further improve answer add `pattern`, `<input type="text" class="form-control required-field" data-type="number" name="superficie" pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?" />`

Comment: One more thing, I don't think `if (input.val() != cleansedValue) {` is required. `input.val(cleansedValue);` can be used direclty

Comment: Thanks guys. I think we got there collectively with quite a nice solution :)